# RTSP Streaming stops after some time

Tags: android, vlc, rtsp

**I am able to stream desktop using RSTP using VLC to android phone.**

But the Stream stops after some time.I tried to search error on web but fail to understand Here is logs

```
08-23 20:25:29.927      380-967/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START {cmp=com.example.vostro.rtspvideodemo/.StreamActivity (has extras)} from pid 17800
08-23 20:25:30.367  17800-17800/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Uri is  rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/stream
08-23 20:25:30.367  17800-17800/? D/MediaPlayer﹕ http youtube = false, scheme = rtsp
08-23 20:25:30.367      126-283/? W/MediaPlayerService﹕ setDataSource(rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/stream)
08-23 20:25:30.417      380-412/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.vostro.rtspvideodemo/.StreamActivity: +468ms
08-23 20:25:30.467    126-18008/? W/ASessionDescription﹕ adding 'a=control' => 'rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/stream'
08-23 20:25:30.467    126-18008/? W/ASessionDescription﹕ adding 'a=control' => 'rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/stream/trackID=0'
08-23 20:25:30.507    126-18008/? W/MyHandler﹕ Missing 'source' field in Transport response. Using RTSP endpoint address.
08-23 20:25:50.957     126-1062/? E/MyHandler﹕ ARTSPController::flags 0
08-23 20:25:50.977  17800-17800/? D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/stream
08-23 20:25:50.977      380-393/? D/BluetoothA2dpService﹕ uri is rtsp://192.168.1.4:8554/streammUri is content://settings/system/notification_sound
08-23 20:25:50.977      380-393/? D/BluetoothA2dpService﹕ Rtsp streaming media, ignoring
```

Comment: How long is "after some time"? If it happens to be 45 or 60 seconds every time, it may be that the RTSP server is not receiving RTCP receiver reports which are used as a session liveness indicator.

Comment: after 45 to 60 seconds. my videoview screen freeze.

Comment: In that case it is likely the receiver reports are not arriving at the RTSP server, causing the server to end the RTSP session after x seconds. This could be due to a firewall, NAT, or RTSP client implementations ( e.g. ffmpeg, and IIRC Android do not send RRs when streaming over TCP).

Comment: @Ralf I tried to stream using http also but the issue is still there. but this time there is no any error in logcat but still stream freezes Can you just suggest me any work around. today i experimented with wowza stream engine. it played there demo video. can you suggest me how to stream with vlc + wowza. plus one more thing i did some search but i can confuse.

Comment: HTTP streaming is an entirely different thing. Have you tried sniffing network traffic? That may be the best way for you to see what's happening.